# Moving data from one range of cells to another with a script Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

First off, I wasn't sure if this question should be in the webapps site or the programming one, but since this is primarily a google sheets question, I put it here.

Basically, in one sheet I have data in cells C14 through F15, so it's 4 columns and 2 rows of data, 8 cells in total. With a script, I'd like to be able to "copy and paste" the values from these cells into B13:E14 on a different sheet.

I understand how to move values from one cell to another with a script, but I'm having trouble doing it with ranges of values.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to research this, though I do understand that sometimes it is hard to know exactly what you are looking for. So please regard this answer as some quick-and-dirty assistance to help you come up to speed.

You can use the `moveTo()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget). Using this method, the amount of code to move data is much shorter than the code required to copy data.

Of course, there are several options for `getRange`:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) used in this example,
  or
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column),
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows),
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Something like this function is all that you need.

```
function moverange(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("C14:F15").moveTo(sheet.getRange("B13"));
}
```